# Php-gd: PHP Extension gd must be loaded & Unable to locate package

Tags: php-gd

Having an issue with php-gd

I inserted this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl php5-mcrypt php5-gd php5-common
```

throughout the process to setup Magento but when I went through Validation, this is what I got:

> "PHP Extension gd must be loaded"

When the warning showed up. I tried to install it again using:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

This was the message that I received:

> "Reading package lists... Done E: Unable to locate package"

I Would like some direction on how to fix this Error.

Comment: I figured out the issue.

Comment: And it was?????

Comment: The idea of stack is to provide an answer..Thanks for nothing

Answer (score 2):

Restarting the webserver after installing php5-gd loads the package.

Answer (score 0):

check. reloading the web server. services such as php-pfm (php5-fpm), fcgi, fastcgi, etc load once and remain in the background.  Adding modules does not impact the running copy.  It must be restarted to load the module into active use.

Answer (score 0):

Use synaptic package manager for easier installation.

After installing and it still does not work, look at the apache modules, mine is at /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-gd.ini

```
; configuration for php GD module
; priority=20
; extension=gd.so
```

Even if the module exists and is installed on the system, it is commented out on the module config. Uncomment it, then restart Apache, then you should be fine.